# Applying the filter function on an Array of Arrays returns an exception in Scala

Tags: arrays, scala, multidimensional-array, filter

I am learning Scala and tried practising some examples on `Arrays`. Below is the example:

```
  scala>var arr = Array(Array(1,2,3), Array(4,5,6));

  scala>arr.map(_.map(_ * 5))
  res42: Array[Array[Int]] = Array(Array(5,10,15),Array(20,25,30))
```

When I tried doing the `filter` method the on above mentioned array in the same way, it resulted in an `error`. Below is the piece of code and the resulting `error`.

```
   scala>arr.filter(_.filter(_ < 5))
   <console>:15: error: type mismatch;
   found   : Array[Int]
   required: Boolean
   o.filter(_.filter(_ < 5))
                    ^
```

Please tell why the `filter` operation isn't working what is the correct way to  use the `filter` method on an array of Arrays ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the objective is to get `Array(Array(1,2,3), Array(4))`, then

```
arr.map(_.filter(_ < 5))
```

If the objective is to get `Array(1,2,3,4)`, then

```
arr.flatten.filter(_ < 5)
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you should read a good book if you're interested in Scala. Using vars is a very bad practice and should be avoided by beginners.

About your example, just to explain why it fails, filter requires as parameter a function with return type `Boolean`. In the inner filter you correctly use `_ < 5` which is expanded to `(x: Int) => x < 5`, a function that returns `true` or `false`. But on the outer filter you used `_.filter(_ < 5)` which is expanded to `(y: Array[Int]) => y.filter((x: Int) => x < 5)`. Here's the issue, `y.filter((x: Int) => x < 5)` will return a new Array, which means the function does not have a return type of `Boolean`, but of an `Array[Int]`.

Comment: Using `Array` is also bad practice and should be avoided by beginners. Storing a mutable collection (`Array`) in a mutable variable (`var`) is bad practice squared.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the signature of the filter:

```
def filter(p: A => Boolean): Repr = filterImpl(p, isFlipped = false)
```

Filter method accepts a [Predicate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predicate_(mathematical_logic)). You may map you internals arrays and then filter by your rules.